# CSS classes in Gmail are not constant

Tags: css, gmail-api

While inspecting the CSS classes in Gmail, I found that the classes like.kV and .De keeps on changing everytime I reload the page. Why does that happens and how does Google achieves this?

Comment: **Probably** an attempt to prevent browser extensions from modifying the CSS and element classes. If you generate it randomly, you are making it difficult for others to customize – they have to account for the randomness, rather than hardcoding the strings. About second half: Any application on the server side can generate a new CSS file (using templates, say) on the fly. If it can maintain proper (randomly generated) class names between the CSS files and the HTML files, the job is done.

Comment: And in response to your second half of the question - it will probably achieve this with javascript - if you'd like to test, turn javascript off in your console and see if it still happens.